# Woocommerce - Guys I'm trying to display 3 random products but skipping the first 3 most recent added products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need your help. I'm trying to display 3 random products but skipping the first 3 most recently added products. Most recent meaning not by query but by global date the product was created.

Heres the code i use to display random  products.

```
$args = array(
'post_type'         => 'product',
'orderby'           => 'rand',
'posts_per_page'    => 3,
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
endwhile;
}
```

Adding 'offset' only skips  the first 3 random. Is there a way to skip first 3 most recently added products?

Comment: Please specify, most recent from a random query or by global date so the last 3 added products were not presented in a result?

Comment: @Artem thanks. Most recent is by global date the product  was created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get three last products and get their IDs using `wp_get_recent_posts` function and map IDs, then add `post__not_in` argument to `WP_query` with these three post IDs

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts([
    'post_type'   => 'product',
    'numberposts' => 3
]);

$last_three_posts = array_map(function($a) { return $a['ID']; }, $recent_posts);

$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'product',
    'orderby'           => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page'    => 3,
    'post__not_in'      => $last_three_posts,
);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Sir. Why are  you  so awesome? I'm a newbie and i would have never solved it.  Thank  you very much.

Comment: @jmcabran no problem, we all were beginners)